# Curried R.view not compiled in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I have a Ramda+Typescript issue I’m wasting way too much time on

Consider this line:
`const rv = R.view(R.lensPath(['a','b']))`

`rv` is a [perfectly legal and working curried statement](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20rv%20%3D%20R.view%28R.lensPath%28%5B%27a%27%2C%27b%27%5D%29%29%0Arv%28%7Ba%3A%7Bb%3A3%7D%7D%29)

However when I put it in my .ts code, TypeScript screams for a *"TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.”*

I am trying to find a solution but nothing… Any idea?

Comment: I don't think any of the Ramda core team have significant Typescript experience. I'm one of them, and I have no experience whatsoever. Occasionally someone suggests that Ramda maintain whatever definition configuration is necessary to make it work with Typescript, most recently in [pull #1999][is]. It never goes anywhere because of our lack of interest in and/or experience with Typescript. But you might find something interesting in that pull request or in [the defintions maintained by donnut][do]. But I may be entirely off, because I don't really know how any of this works. [do]: https://gith

Comment: My answer got converted into the comment above (probably properly as it wasn't truly an answer.)  But the two links included were lost in the suffle, and they might actually help: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1999 and https://github.com/donnut/typescript-ramda

Comment: Thank you @ScottSauyet Apparently my Ramda typings file was a bit old and the typings for R.view was very partial. Everything is compiling now